# Regex- Ignore a constant string that matches a pattern

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have this regular expression:

```
\b[A-Z]{1}[A-Z]{0,7}[0-9]?\b|\b[0-9]{2,3}\b
```

The **desired** output is as highlighted:

JOHN went to `LONDON` one fine day.
JOHN had lunch in a `PUB`.
JOHN then moved to `CHICAGO`.
I don't want `JOHN` to be highlighted.
John does not want this to match the pattern.
Neither this.
But `THIS1` should match the pattern.
Also the other `70` times that the pattern should match.

**Observed** output:

`JOHN` went to `LONDON` one fine day.
`JOHN` had lunch in a `PUB`.
`JOHN` then moved to `CHICAGO`.
`I` don't want `JOHN` to be highlighted.
John does not want this to match the pattern.
Neither this.
But `THIS1` should match the pattern.
Also the other `70` times that the pattern should match.

The regex works partly but I don't want two constant strings- `JOHN` and `I` to match as part of this regex. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead to exclude those matches. Also, your pattern seems rather "redundant", you may shorten it considerably using grouping and removing unnecessary subpatterns:

```
\b(?!(?:JOHN|I)\b)(?:[A-Z]{1,8}[0-9]?|[0-9]{2,3})\b
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sUOCSd/3)

The `(?!(?:JOHN|I)\b)` is the negative lookahead that fails the match if the word matched is equal to `I` or `JOHN`.

Note that `{1}` can always be omitted as any unquantified pattern is matched once. `[A-Z]{1}[A-Z]{0,7}` is actually equal to `[A-Z]{1,8}`.

**Pattern details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?!(?:JOHN|I)\b)` - the word matched cannot be equal to `JOHN` or `I`
- `(?:[A-Z]{1,8}[0-9]?|[0-9]{2,3})` - one of the two alternatives:

  - `[A-Z]{1,8}[0-9]?` - 1 to 8 uppercase ASCII letters followed with an optional (1 or 0) digit
  - `|`  - or
  - `[0-9]{2,3}`  - 2 to 3 digits
- `\b` - trailing word boundary